# Transforming n-ary relationship to SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, erd

atm I'm struggling with transforming n-ary relationships from my ERD to SQL Tables.

In university we learned, that for each n-ary relationship we create an intersection table with the PK as a collection of the PKs as FKs. But what to do in this case:
[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHqny.png)[image]

Are there reasons to create an intersection table here or is it fine to just put the PKs of "Department" and "Period" as FKs into the "acquisition process" table to reduce the number of tables?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, are you running out of tables? :-)

In your example diagram, it appears that a given acquisition process can refer to multiple periods and multiple departments.

But if you put the FK's into the acquisition process table, you can only put one value in each FK column, so you will only be able to refer to one period and one department for each process, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AcquisitionProcess (
  process_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  period_id INT,  -- one id value
  department_id INT, -- one id value
  FOREIGN KEY (period_id) REFERENCES Period(period_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES Department(department_id)
);
```

How will you handle a case when an acquisition process applies to two departments and three periods?

When you have multiple n-ary relationships (sometimes also called many-to-many relationships), you really do need one intersection table per relationship.

---

Re your comment:

If you want an acquisition process to refer to one period and one department, you put the FK columns in the AcquisitionProcess table, and you have one line to each of the referenced tables.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

`But if you put the FK's into the acquisition process table, you can only put one value in each FK column, so you will only be able to refer to one period and one department for each process, like this:`

...and this is the intended result. Then I assume my ERD is wrong, but how do i show this circumstance in the ERD? Do I have to split it in two relationships?

Comment: Great, thank you very much! But now I have one more question. Let's get back to the ERD in my first Post. How should I interpret the ERD, if (1,1) was also (1,n)? I thought that the (1,1) implies, that a Process can only refer to one Period and one Department, but you corrected me and wrote `it appears that a given acquisition process can refer to multiple periods and multiple departments.`. What is the difference in the meaning now, if I replace the (1,1) in my example ERD with (1,n)?

Comment: I've never seen an ERD with a diamond that has multiple links like that. When you use the diamond, put "1..*" or "N" on the left and "1" or "0..1" on the right. Use a separate diamond-shaped associative entity for each relationship.